# Zoom meeting crashes in Kubuntu 22.04 when you share computer audio

Tags: sound, zoom-meeting

I use zoom (version 5.13.7(683)) for meetings. I extensively share audio from my computer.
But after the upgrade I started to notice this strange issue, when I share computer sound (by clicking on the ShareScreen -> Advanced -> Computer Audio), I found that it crashes with a "Streamer" error. The error message says - pa_stream_writable_size() failed: Connection terminated.

Pre requisite for reproducing this issue:

1. Kubuntu 22.04 LTS installed with all latest updates
2. Zoom version 5.13.7(683)
3. Clementine Music Player (optional)

How to reproduce:

- Step 1: Play some music in your laptop (I use clementine music player)
- Step 2: Start zoom
- Step 3: Click on "Share Screen"
- Step 4: Go to "Advanced Tab"
- Step 5: click on "Computer Audio"
- Step 6: Now stop the audio share by clicking on the top toolbar which appeared on top of zoom
- Step 7: Now try to redo from step 3

At this time you should get the stream error.

Comment: I uninstalled Kubuntu 22.04 and then installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04 and still the same error appears. Interesting this is it worked flawless for few days (3 days to be precise) and then this started to happen again. So I think the issue is definitely with something in 22.04. When I was in 20.04 no such issues were there. Please help.

Comment: I am stumped. I have Ubuntu Studio 22.04 on another laptop but that doesn't have this problem? So not sure how to do an apples to apples comparison between the two laptops and get to a solution.

Comment: Even in Ubuntu Studio 22.04 I am having this issue. So two laptops with Ubuntu Studio 22.04 I tested and both got the same issue. I uninstalled and installed Linux Mint and even then the same issue. So this seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the solution.
Try to delete the ~/.config/pulse folder and reboot the machine (better still to just rename it and reboot).

And STOP using Clementine.

In all my cases the common denominator is Clementine music player which is causing this issue. When I tried with VLC everything works for now.
Please note that the Clementine used to work sporadically and then conked out. So not sure even VLC do the same. For now it's working.